# Where to change datasource in Jboss WildFly war file

Tags: jboss, wildfly, datasource, war, jboss-web

My current environment uses Linux, CentOS, WildFly 16.  There are multiple datasources and it is all established externally in the standalone.xml.  The application(s) in WildFly work just fine.

The issue I am dealing with is when I deploy the war file using command line interface (`./bin/jboss-cli.sh`) the application will use the existing datasource and I would like to change the datasource.  For example App1.war uses MySqlDS1 datasource and App2_test.war uses MySqlDS2 datasource.  I plan to overwrite App1.war with App2_test.war.  The code will be `mv App2_test.war App1.war` .  At that time the App1.war will be pointed to MySqlDS2 datasource, I believe since it now contains the App2_test code - that is the issue.

I need to change the App2_test.war file to point to MySqlDS1.  I need to find the file that associates the URL to the datasource in the standalone.xml - I believe.  I looked into web.xml but it does not exist in my war file and may not be provided in releases above EAP 6.  I also looked into jboss-web.xml but unable to find file.  I only have Manifest.mf in /META-INF and nothing in /WEB-INF/lib.

What file needs to be updated?

Comment: Does your code have `@PersistenceContext` annotations?  Normally this is stored in `META-INF/persistence.xml` but that's not a requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `persistence.xml`.  In the `META-INF` directory, only `MANIFEST.MF` is available.

Comment: So the code must have the annotations.  This is a bit of a pain as you need to change the code to change persistence providers.

Comment: I understand the `jboss-web.xml` or `web.xml` file would provide the <context-root>. However I do not see the relation between the WAR file and its datasource, specifically if there are different applications on the server and each have there own database.  Maybe I just can't find the existing annotation.

Comment: I found the missing .class files under ImportedClasses.  These class files xxServet.class contain the annotations of the hardcoded datasource I was looking for and just what @stdunbar stated.  The code is ` @javax.annotation.Resource(lookup="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS2")`. Now may I update these class files with the new datasource name? Should I download javax.annotation.jar online and add to my library?  Or perhaps use another method.